# xpath returning empty text when web-scraping in r

Tags: css, r, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape information from https://www.kff.org/interactive/subsidy-calculator. For instance, put state=California, zip=90001, income=20000, no coverage, 1 people, 1 adult, no children, age=21, no tobacco.

We get the following:
https://www.kff.org/interactive/subsidy-calculator/#state=ca&zip=94704&income-type=dollars&income=20000&employer-coverage=0&people=1&alternate-plan-family=individual&adult-count=1&adults%5B0%5D%5Bage%5D=21&adults%5B0%5D%5Btobacco%5D=0&child-count=0

I would like to get the numbers for "estimated financial help" and "your cost for a silver plan" (they are bolded-blue in the "Results" grey box, for some reason I can't upload the screenshot). When I use the xpath for the numbers, I get back empty string. This is not the case if I were to retrieve some other text (not in the grey box). I wonder what could be wrong with this. I have attached code below. Please forgive me if this is a stupid question since I'm very new to web-scraping. Thank you!

```r
state = tolower('CA')
zip = 94704
income = 20000
people = 1
adult = 1
children = 0

url = paste0("https://www.kff.org/interactive/subsidy-calculator/#state=", state, "&zip=", zip, "&income-type=dollars&income=", income, "&employer-coverage=0&people=", people, "&alternate-plan-family=individual&adult-count=", adult, "&adults%5B0%5D%5Bage%5D=21&adults%5B0%5D%5Btobacco%5D=0&child-count=", children)

# This returns empty string
r = read_html(url) %>%
      html_nodes(xpath ='//*[@id="subsidy-calculator-new"]/div[5]/div/div/dl/dd[1]/span') %>% html_text()

# This returns "Number of children (20 and younger) enrolling in Marketplace coverage", a line that's not in the grey box.
r = read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="subsidy-form"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/p') %>%
  html_text()
```

Answer (score 0):

The values are generated through scripts that run on the page. Your current method won't allow for this hence your result. You are likely better off using a method which allows scripts to run such as RSelenium.

The form you complete #subsidy-form feeds values into a template in a script tag #results-template. The associated calculations are covered in this script https://www.kff.org/wp-content/themes/kaiser-foundation-2016/interactives/subsidy-calculator/2019/calculator.js?ver=1.7.7  where you will find the logic and the pre-set values such as poverty lines per year.

The simplest quick view is probably to inspect the javascript variables when the new `SubsidyCalculator` object is created to process the form i.e. js starting with `var sc = new SubsidyCalculator`. You could 'reverse engineer' those variables with your values plus the values returned from the json below which I think, but haven't confirmed, feed the 6 variables that begin with `kff_sc`, according to zipcode, into the calculator e.g. `silver: kff_sc.silver` . You get an idea of the ballpark figures given there are default values given at top of script.

Figures in relation to zipcode are retrieved from this: https://www.kff.org/wp-content/themes/kaiser-foundation-2016/interactives/subsidy-calculator/2019/json/zips/94.json  where the last two numbers before .json are the first two numbers of zipcode. You can determine this from the input validation script: https://www.kff.org/wp-content/themes/kaiser-foundation-2016/interactives/subsidy-calculator/2019/shared.js?ver=1.7.7

```js
var bucket = $( this ).val().substring( 0, 2 );
  if ( kff_sc.buckets[bucket] ) return;
  $.ajax( '/wp-content/themes/vip/kaiser-foundation-2016/interactives/subsidy-calculator/2019/json/zips/' + bucket + '.json',
```

The first two digits determine the bucket.

All in all you could likely implement your own calculator but you would be re-inventing the wheel. Seems easier to just automate the browser and then extract the resultant values.

Comment: Did this answer your question please?